# Web Service HTTP 404

Tags: java, webservice

Es la primera vez que realizo un intento de WebService , estoy trabajando con Eclipse , y tengo la siguiente clase:

```
@Path("/AltaCliente")
public class WebServicePushNotifications {

    @POST
    @Path("/alta")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Dejo la estructura de mi proyecto , 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento acceder al get a través de

> http://localhost:8080/push_notifications/AltaCliente
>   http://localhost:8080/push_notifications/AltaCliente/alta

me da error HTTP 404

dejo el log de la consola de mi JBOSS

```
Starting weld service for deployment push_notifications.war
12:13:10,874 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS018210: Register web context: /push_notifications
12:13:11,033 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.28-jbossorg-6  for context '/push_notifications'
12:13:11,753 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.2.Final-redhat-2
12:13:12,389 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) JBAS015859: Deployed "push_notifications.war" (runtime-name : "push_notifications.war")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que esa clase tienes dos **`web services`**, lo que te falto fue ponerle un **`path`** a cada **`web service`**, por ejemplo te dejo tu mismo web service solo con la anotacion de **`path`** solo le puse alta como ejemplo:

```
@POST
@Path("/alta")
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public String post(String body) {
    System.out.println("body: " + body);
    String response = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/OvnipressCore-0.0.1/AltaCliente");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response += output;
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return response + " - Antel body: "+ body;
}
```

Cuando lo consumas lo haces asi:

> http://localhost:8080/push_notifications/AltaCliente/alta

Comment: literalmente me traje esto a mi clase y aun asi me dice error 404 , >$

Comment: Modifica el otro web service con @pat tambien y si puedes mostrar el log

Comment: Edite mi pregunta y disculpa la burrada pero el servers - console ni se mueve el log

Comment: Ya vi ahora el problema es que mira cuando haces un Get es para obtener información es como un select, cuando haces Post es para cuando vas hacer un update o un insert

Comment: Solo cambia anotación post por por get me cuentas

Comment: Bueno no eh tenido exito tampoco agregandole GET envez de POST , me parece bastante extraño

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72923/discussion-between-raul-cacacho-and-bruno-sosa-fast-tag).